# Workaround for mac custom icons which don't show up when pasted into documents properties

Tags: finder, monterey, icon, customization

Since some version update of macOS Monterey (don't remember which one), the custom icons I previously created by pasting .jpg or .png images into some documents properties (top left) stopped working and showed up as "blank icons" on the Desktop.

Very irritating.

I recently upgraded to Ventura, hoping for a correction : no dice :-( .
Then I tried multiple alternate methods for creating custom icns, but the problem subsisted.

Finally I found a very simple workaround :

- paste into the document properties your custom image
- right click the blank document icon and select "Rename"
- cancel the rename
  => the custom icn shows up !

Obviously, the cancelled rename forces a Finder's refresh for the icon, and solved my problem.

[image]